How do I render high degree polynomial functions?
I have calculated a function using regression in a python script. Now I want to plot that function in Latex. This works fine as long as the function is of low polynomial degree and fits within the specified y-value range.

However if the functions polynomial degree is too large I run into two issues.

Range. The plot rescales for some reason, ignoring the specified y-range and making the plot useless. I'd like it to show only the specified range, cutting of parts of the function that leave that range.
Precision. The function doesn't look correct, it doesn't go through the last couple of points. I think this may have to do with precision, but if I add too many digits after the decimal it doesn't render at all anymore. Is there a better way to do this? Pgfplots linear regression doesn't work for functions of degree larger than two, so that's off. Worst case I'd just render it in Matplotlib and paste an image into my document but I'd really hate to do that as I want vector graphics. Maybe one can create those externally and import them somehow?

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=10cm, height=8cm,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        ymin=-0.5, ymax=1.5,    % Why does this not work?
        xmin=0, xmax=10,
        grid=major,
        domain=0:10,
        samples=200,
        % clip mode=individual,   % Doesn't change anything
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)}, anchor=north, legend columns=-1},
    ]

    % Training data points (scattered around the ground truth function)
    \addplot[only marks, mark=*, red] 
    coordinates {
        (0.00, 0.10) (0.50, 0.10) (1.00, 0.38) (1.50, 0.67) (2.00, 0.43) (2.50, 0.54) (3.00, 1.00) (3.50, 0.92) (4.00, 0.75) (4.50, 1.01) (5.00, 0.86) (5.50, 0.89) (6.00, 1.05) (6.50, 0.62) (7.00, 0.64) (7.50, 0.84) (8.00, 0.71) (8.50, 0.91) (9.00, 0.60) (9.50, 0.41) (10.00, 0.89)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Training Data}

    \addplot[green, thick] {1.42410747e-01*x^0 +2.53246271e-01*x^1 -2.13016452e-02*x^2};
    \addlegendentry{Signal}

    \addplot[blue, thick] {9.93428312e-02*x^0 +3.16704047e+03*x^1 -2.19161295e+04*x^2 +6.58070075e+04*x^3 -1.15687440e+05*x^4 +1.34879192e+05*x^5 -1.11647187e+05*x^6 +6.84376510e+04*x^7 -3.19378759e+04*x^8 +1.15590339e+04*x^9 -3.28376090e+03*x^10 +7.37356658e+02*x^11 -1.31196909e+02*x^12 +1.84621578e+01*x^13 -2.04081811e+00*x^14 +1.74939738e-01*x^15 -1.13821338e-02*x^16 +5.42814421e-04*x^17 -1.78821540e-05*x^18 +3.63418435e-07*x^19 -3.43158559e-09*x^20};
    \addlegendentry{Overfitted Model}

    \addplot[yellow, thick] {4.79686795e-01*x^0 +4.02298192e-02*x^1};
    \addlegendentry{Underfitted Model}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Thanks for any help in advance!

you could presumably just generate the data points externally and then plot using those points rather than evaluating the function in pgf. Alternatively if you generate the plot externally you can still import it as vector graphics if you generate it as pdf rathen than a png bitmap.

You can improve the accuracy somewhat using good applied math pactices, but ultimately the round off error for pgfmath will kill you.

@DavidCarlisle You mean simply sample the function at - idk, a thousand? - x-values and then just copy them into latex and connect them?
Do you have an idea how to fix the range issue though?

If I recall correctly pgfplots has some predefined functions for plotting from a table of sample points rather than passing it a function, but I don't use pgfplots much I'll let someome else answer. pgfmath (especially with its default fixed (not floating) point tex dimen arithmetic isn't really suitable for any numerically unstable functions,

It works if you reduce the domain so that |x|<1.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=10cm, height=8cm,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        ymin=-0.5, ymax=1.5,
        xmin=0, xmax=10,
        grid=major,
        domain=0:10,
        samples=200,
        % clip mode=individual,   % Doesn't change anything
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)}, anchor=south, legend columns=-1},
    ]

    % Training data points (scattered around the ground truth function)
    \addplot[only marks, mark=*, red] 
    coordinates {
        (0.00, 0.10) (0.50, 0.10) (1.00, 0.38) (1.50, 0.67) (2.00, 0.43) (2.50, 0.54) (3.00, 1.00) (3.50, 0.92) (4.00, 0.75) (4.50, 1.01) (5.00, 0.86) (5.50, 0.89) (6.00, 1.05) (6.50, 0.62) (7.00, 0.64) (7.50, 0.84) (8.00, 0.71) (8.50, 0.91) (9.00, 0.60) (9.50, 0.41) (10.00, 0.89)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Training Data}

    \addplot[green, thick] {(-2.13016452e-02*x +2.53246271e-01)*x +1.42410747e-01};
    \addlegendentry{Signal}

    \addplot[blue, thick, domain=0:1] {(((((((((((((((((((-3.43158559e-09*x +3.63418435e-07)*x -1.78821540e-05)*x +5.42814421e-04)*x -1.13821338e-02)*x % 20-16
      +1.74939738e-01)*x -2.04081811e+00)*x +1.84621578e+01)*x -1.31196909e+02)*x +7.37356658e+02)*x -3.28376090e+03)*x % 15-10
      +1.15590339e+04)*x -3.19378759e+04)*x +6.84376510e+04)*x -1.11647187e+05)*x +1.34879192e+05)*x -1.15687440e+05)*x % 9-4
      +6.58070075e+04)*x -2.19161295e+04)*x +3.16704047e+03)*x +9.93428312e-02}; % 3-0
    \addlegendentry{Overfitted Model}

    \addplot[yellow, thick] {4.79686795e-01 +4.02298192e-02*x};
    \addlegendentry{Underfitted Model}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Thank you, but I don't understand why I would do that? I want the function to go through all of the data points, not just the first three.

Theoretically, you could create a set of polynomial solutions set at x=0, x=2, x=4 etc.  But it would be easier just to generate a table of values to read.  Or you could just fake it with a buch of vertical lines passing through the data points.

Hey, I need a little more help. I now have a csv table with a column for each function and 200 linearly sampled points for each. Plotting the low-degree functions works as expected. But the high degree poly still leads to the y-range exploding and not the line leaving and rejoining the plot as in your example. I'm out of ideas. I could sample points in a way that all of them are within the y-range but that's not what I want, because I'd have horizontal lines connecting the fragments instead of the line just leaving the plot.

Do the data look okay?  Are the numbers within \pm 10^5?  I have no idea why ymin/ymax works sometimes and not others.  I vaguely recall a problem doing calculations involving very large numbers and a special keyword (not ymax) to prevent that.

Aha! restrict y to domain=min:max  Use larger numbers than ymin and ymax to accurately interpolate the intersections with the edge of the box.
